# WordPress/WooCommerce: Don't show products from a specific category, except

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce problem that I can't solve myself. Currently, I'm using this code to hide  products that are in a specific category.

```
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {
  $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );
  $tax_query[] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array( 'my-category' ),
    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
  );
  $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
```

This works good so far. But I'd like to modify this code with one exception...

When I'm IN the product category *'my-category'*, the products are obviously not being displayed, too. However, I'd like to change the code so it  does not apply when I'm in the category page of 'my-category'. In this category, I want the products to be shown.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can check that using is_product_category() function

```
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {
   if( ! is_product_category( 'my-category' ) {

      $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );
      $tax_query[] = array(
         'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
         'field' => 'slug',
         'terms' => array( 'my-category' ),
         'operator' => 'NOT IN'
      );
      $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I can't believe it's that simple ;) Works perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

Use the [is_tax](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax) function to check the page.
Here is an example.

```
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {
    if ( is_tax( 'product_cat', 'my-category' ) ) return; // <--

  $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );
  $tax_query[] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array( 'my-category' ),
    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
  );
  $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}
```